# python pathos multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, jupyter-notebook, pathos

I am trying to use the pathos multiprocessing for a simple function for which I pass an array, it splits into parallel processes and then joins at the end.

Here is the code I ported over from using the multiprocessing function, and then instead of importing multiprocessing, I imported pathos.

```
import sys
import gender_guesser.detector as gender
import time
from pathos import multiprocessing as multiprocessing


d = gender.Detector()

def guess_gender (name):
    n = name.title() # make first letter upper case and the rest lower case 
    g = d.get_gender(n) # guess gender
    return g

ls = ['john','joe','amamda','derick','peter','ashley','john','joe','amamda','derick','peter','ashley']

t=time.time()

results=[]


def callBack(x):
    results.append(x)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1, maxtasksperchild=1)

for n in ls:
    print (n)
    pool.apply_async(guess_gender,args=[n],callback=callBack)

pool.close()
pool.join()

results = pd.concat(results)


print(time.time()-t)
```

However, I get this error:

```
ValueError: No objects to concatenate
```

I am not sure how I extract the results of the output. The documentation on pathos is thin.

Does anyone have any ideas or experience?

FYI i am running python in jupyter notebooks.

Comment: what line is throwing this error?

Comment: results = pd.concat(results) Thank you